# 7-8 Volts at Porch Light Switch

Tags: wiring, lighting

My wife changed three incandescent porch light bulbs with LED bulbs and it kicked the circuit breaker.  I replaced the LED bulbs with incandescent bulbs.  When I turn on the light switch for the exterior light it now reads 7-8 volts at the switch.  There are two lights on the same breaker.  The interior light reads 120 volts at the switch.  The wiring from the circuit breaker goes to the indoor light and from there to the outdoor light.  The indoor light reads 120 volts at the light switch and as I mentioned the outdoor light reads 7-8 volts at the light switch.
I’m not sure whether the problem is the wiring connection from the good indoor light, the connection where the home wiring connects to the outdoor lamp or the lamp wiring is bad.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With only 7-8 volts your hot has opened some place unless using a low z meter. When the neutral opens with a normal meter many times you will read 120-50v but just a few is a sign that a connection at a wire nut probably failed unless using spring tension blocks wago is a popular brand and they normally work well unless there is a catastrophic failure (something that causes the breaker to trip) then they get loose like a back stab.
Since your indoor light works check the junction there. Then in the non working fixture closest to the working fixture it is probably a push in or bad wire nut connection.